# SQL result column showing no value due to precision?

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer-division

Here is a query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 25/8175133
```

This show 0 as result, while the actual value is 0.00000305805

I tried

```
SELECT CAST(25/8175133 AS DECIMAL)
SELECT CAST(25/8175133 AS AS DOUBLE PRECISION)
```

but nothing seems to work.
Is there are way to show very low fraction values in our SELECT output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When PostgreSQL divides two integer values the result is an integer. If you want decimal places you need to include at least one operand with decimal places.

You can do:

```
SELECT 1.0 * 25/8175133
```

or:

```
SELECT 25.0/8175133
```

Result:

```
?column?
--------
0.000003058054223704984372
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is trying to return to you the same type you supplied.  You can resolve this like this as well:

```sql
SELECT 25.0/8175133;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 25/8175133 :: decimal => 0.000003058054223704984372

SELECT 25/8175133 :: double precision => 3.0580542237049843e-06

SELECT 25/8175133 :: numeric => 0.000003058054223704984372
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ROUND`

```
 Select round(25/8175133::decimal, 11);
```

Refer this for sample output http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/77c08/41